# Angularjs delay append new data and display old data 1s

Tags: angularjs

It delays append new data and display old data 1s when I click: https://youtu.be/KeqRdGueekg

In controller:

```
   myApp.controller('Notebook', function($scope, $http){
    //Display Note click NoteBook
    $scope.xl_note = function(id){
        $http.get("/thunder_note/notebooks/show_note?id=" + id)
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.dataNote = response.data;
            });
    };
});
```

In view:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="list_body list_body_note_of_notebook">
        <div class="list_content show_noteaas" ng-repeat="data in dataNote.Note">
            <a href="/thunder_note/notes/note_detail/{{data.id}}" style="text-decoration: none;">
                <p class="title">{{data.title}}</p>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call /thunder_note/notes/note_detail/
you do 2 things calling api and redirecting page 
the page ridects immidiate so there is allready old data 
but api response takes some time  for getting response 
so clear  $scope.dataNote ="";  before your calling api